# Requre a type implementing a trait be repr(packed)

Tags: rust

For some OpenGL code, I created a trait `Vertex`. currently it looks like this

```
trait Vertex: Sized + Clone {
//...
}
```

Because of the way `Vertex`'s are used in my program, its very important that anything is a vertex uses the packed representation. If there is any padding it could potentially create problems. Is there any way I can constrain the Vertex trait to only types that use the packed representation? If need be, I could just define my own marker trait that I manually implement for everything that implements `Vertex`. It seems like something the compiler could easily surface and enforce properly, but I haven't been able to find any kind of representation trait. Thanks

Comment: I believe in current Rust you must implement a marker trait. If violating the contract can cause UB, then the marker trait should be an unsafe trait, so it must be implemented in an unsafe block. If the API needs to be convenient, you can implement a derive proc macro that implements the unsafe trait when it can prove that it's safe to do so - e.g. when it finds `#[repr(packed)]` among the type attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question gave me the impetus to finish a project I had lying around to do exactly this.

I just pushed it to [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/repr-trait). I've been using it for some similar work (dealing with some strange FFI's), but never published it.

It lets you write this code:

```rust
use repr_trait::Packed;

// Safety: Only safe to call when T has #[repr(packed)]
unsafe fn safe_when_packed<T>(_param: T) {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn safe_wrapper<T: Packed>(param: T) {
    // Safety: Safe because T is guaranteed to be #[repr(packed)]
    unsafe {
        safe_when_packed(param)
    }
}

#[derive(Packed, Default)]
#[repr(packed)]
struct PackedData(u32, u8);

safe_wrapper(PackedData(123, 45));
```

But this is a compile error:

```rust
#[derive(Packed)]
struct NotPacked(u32, u8);
```

You would write your vertex trait as:

```rust
trait Vertex: Sized + Clone + Packed {
//...
}
```